# R - Group By Multiple Columns

Tags: r

I'm trying to run analysis on a dataset that categorizes companies into 20 different industries, and some 800 categories. Each industry category is in it's own column. Here's a sample dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(biz.name=c("goog", "face", "eb"), worth=c(100, 200, 300),
cat1=c("social", "social", "social"), cat2=c(NA, "search", "finance"),
cat3=c(NA, NA, "commerce"))
```

I'd like to know how to run analysis on different types of categories. For instance, how would I get the the average worth of different categories, "social" or "finance". Each company can be in up to 20 categories (non-repeating per row).

The dplyr package is my normal go-to group_by method, but chaining doesn't seem to work for multiple columns

```
cat.test <- df %>% 
  group_by(cat1:cat2) %>%
  summarise (avg = mean(is.na(worth)))
```

The code produces a measure for each permutation of businesses with a combination of multiple categories, rather that each category individually. In the sample data frame, the category social should have a total net worth of 600 and mean of 300.

I've looked at multiple tutorials, but haven't found one that can group_by for multiple columns. Thanks and let me know if i can make this question any more clear.

[UPDATE: edited data.frame code]

Comment: op! sorry folks. i fixed

Comment: Shouldn't the sum be 600 and the mean 200. 600/3 = 200?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `data.table` this way:

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df[-1]), id.vars='worth', value.name='category')[,.(worth=sum(worth)),category]
#   category worth
#1:   social   600
#2:       NA   400
#3:   search   200
#4:  finance   300
#5: commerce   300
```

Answer (score 4):

I cleaned up your code and was able to get a result out using the `data.table` package:

```
df <- data.frame(biz.name=c("goog", "face", "eb"), worth=c(100, 200, 300), 
                 cat1=c("social", "social", "social"), cat2=c("NA", "search", "finance"),
                 cat3=c("NA", "NA", "commerce"))

library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, Mean:=mean(worth), by=list(cat1, cat2)]

> dt
     biz.name  worth   cat1    cat2     cat3 Mean
1:       goog    100 social      NA       NA  100
2:       face    200 social  search       NA  200
3:         eb    300 social finance commerce  300
```

Comment: I think OP needs to melt `cat1/2/3` and then aggregate.

Comment: @thelatemail So in SQL terms, you're saying he should probably be grouping by all three columns, and then taking an aggregate, such as the `mean`, from that?

Comment: It's getting close. The above solution doesn't quite work because data table doesn't group by the unique factors of each category. Both aggregate and dplyr would normally do that, if it was all contained in a single column. The trick is multiple columns. If there are two common categorical variables contained in separate columns, the code would have to recognize that.

Comment: @tom I didn't understand your comment `data.table doesn't group by the unique factors of each category` .  I think the what we are doing with `dplyr` i.e. `df %>% group_by(cat1, cat2) %>% mutate(Mean=mean(worth))` is equivalent to the data.table method posted here.

Answer (score 3):

Using `tidyr`, something like:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  gather(variable, category, -biz.name, -worth) %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarise(worth=sum(worth))
#Source: local data frame [5 x 2]
# 
#  category worth
#1 commerce   300
#2  finance   300
#3   search   200
#4   social   600
#5       NA   400
```

This matches your requested sum figure for 'social'